# Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs Find users who updated there phone number

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to find all users who changed there phone number on AzureAd. I was hoping I could find that information on Get-AzureAdAuditDirectoryLogs but I am not able to find anything.

```
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -All $true -Filter "activityDateTime le 2019-12-18 and Category eq 'UserManagement' and OperationType eq 'Update' and ActivityDisplayName eq 'Update user'"
```

My question is. Where and how can I find when a users has added or updated a field on there account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, your command should work.

```
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -All $true -Filter "activityDateTime le 2020-01-04 and Category eq 'UserManagement' and OperationType eq 'Update' and ActivityDisplayName eq 'Update user'"
```

[image]

> but I am not able to find anything

The reason that I can find maybe the `activityDateTime le 2019-12-18`, `le` means `less than or equal to`, so the max value is `2019-12-18 00:00:00`, if the activity happened in e.g. `2019-12-18 01:17:12`, then it will not be returned in the result, you need to use `activityDateTime le 2019-12-19`.

**Update:**

If you want to export the new phone numbers to csv file, try the script below.

**Note**: When use the query above, it will also include the other user update information, like `JobTitle`, `Department`, etc. So we need to exclude them in the script, and there are `Office phone(TelephoneNumber)` and `Mobile phone(Mobile)` in Azure AD user properties, in my sample, they are both included. You can also modify this line `if($log.TargetResources.ModifiedProperties.NewValue[1].Trim(""",""") -eq 'Mobile' -or $log.TargetResources.ModifiedProperties.NewValue[1].Trim(""",""") -eq 'TelephoneNumber')` in the script to meet your own requirement.

[image]

```
$users = @()
$logs = Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -All $true -Filter "activityDateTime le 2020-01-07 and Category eq 'UserManagement' and OperationType eq 'Update' and ActivityDisplayName eq 'Update user'"
foreach($log in $logs){
    if($log.TargetResources.ModifiedProperties.NewValue[1].Trim(""",""") -eq 'Mobile' -or $log.TargetResources.ModifiedProperties.NewValue[1].Trim(""",""") -eq 'TelephoneNumber'){
            $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
            UserPrincipalName = $log.TargetResources.UserPrincipalName
            Phone = $log.TargetResources.ModifiedProperties.NewValue[0].Trim("["",""]")
            }
        $users += $obj
    }
}
$users | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\phone.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The csv file will be like below, including the `UserPrincipalName` and its new phone number.

[image]

Comment: Where can I find the new phone number from this point? I need to export the new phone numbers to CSV

Comment: @Vel I will update for you on Monday, now I’m out of the office.:-)

Comment: this is perfect thank you. This might be a long shot but we are also using a custom extension field. I cant seem to find any updates on it. Any direction you can point me how to extract changes on those custom fields?

Comment: @Vel My way is to update the info which you want to track of the test user, then look into the `TargetResources.ModifiedProperties`, we will find the updated information. There are some character `[]`,`""`, then we use `Trim()` to exclude them.